# Swift combine publishers where one hasn't sent a value yet

Tags: swift, combine

I have a publisher which would need re-evaluating on day change, but should continue to emit values at any other time.

As such, I thought I could use a `NotificationCenter` publisher for the `UIApplication.significantTimeChangeNotification` notification and combine it with my publisher such that the combine emission process would re-run on either on data change or day change and hence re-evaluate the map filter. See a rough outline of that code below.

The problem is that there is no published event by `NotificationCenter` at the point in time that this is setup and hence, none of the following `map` etc calls actually evaluate. `merge(with:)` won't work as the two publishers publish different types, but `combineLatest(_:)` and `zip(_:)` both won't emit events until both publishers have emitted a single event.

I can validate that my code operates as expected by adding `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: UIApplication.significantTimeChangeNotification, object: nil)` after this code, but that is undesirable due to it potentially signalling other areas of the app that an actual time change has occurred when it hasn't

```swift
private func todaysDate() -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"
    return formatter.string(from: Date())
}

@Published var entities: [MyEntity]

let dayChangePublisher = NotificationCenter.default
    .publisher(for: UIApplication.significantTimeChangeNotification)

$entities.combineLatest(dayChangePublisher)
    .map(\.0) // Only pass on the entity for further operations
    .map { entities -> MyEntity? in
        let today = todaysDate()
        return entities?.first(where: { $0.id == today })
    }
    ...remainder of combine code
```

Can this combination of publishers and evaluation of events occur with the current Swift combine framework? Like the behaviour I'd expect from `merge(with:)` but where the publishers emit two different types.

edit:
I found one solution where I map the notification publisher to a nil array

```swift
let dayChangePublisher = NotificationCenter.default
    .publisher(for: UIApplication.significantTimeChangeNotification)
    .map { _ ➝ [MyEntity]? in
        return nil
    }
```

And then use `merge` and `compactMap` to avoid passing any nil values on

```swift
let mergedPub = repo.$entities
        .merge(with: dayChangePublisher)
        .compactMap { entity -> MyEntity? in
            let today = todaysDate()
            return entities?.first { $0.id == today }
        }
        .share()
```

It works, but maybe a bit cumbersome if anyone has a better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood your question, you need a `combineLatest` that is not blocked by not having an initial value from one of the publishers.

You can achieve that with `.prepend(value)` operator. In this case, since you don't care about the actual value, map first to `Void`, then prepend a `Void`. It would work like so:

```
let dayChangePublisher = NotificationCenter.default
    .publisher(for: UIApplication.significantTimeChangeNotification)

$entities.combineLatest(
   dayChangePublisher
      .map { _ in }
      .prepend(()) // make sure to prepend a () value
    )
    .map(\.0) // Only pass on the entity for further operations
    .map { entities -> MyEntity? in
        let today = todaysDate()
        return entities?.first(where: { $0.id == today })
    }
    //...
```

Comment: Missed an opening bracket in `prepend`. Should be `.prepend(())`, easy fix, but just in case some comes along and copies code

Comment: @DamienPontifex, hmm..., I think it works without explicitly passing `()` aka `Void` as a parameter

Comment: I did try just with `prepend()` and I didn't think it sent. But I only tried once and had `.prepend(())` working, so stuck with that anyway.

Comment: If you call `prepend()` without passing an argument, it evaluates to an empty variadic list of `()`, which it then does prepend but since its empty it’s functionally a non-op. Since `()` (or unit, if you will) is a type like any other, even though it has a singular value, you do need to explicitly pass that value.

Comment: @CharlesMaria, ah.. you both are right. Good catch!

Comment: Thanks this helped me; I hope you don't mind but I edited the answer to make the fix of mapping to void and prepending void to the NotificationCenter publisher so that it works with combineLatest much clearer.

Comment: @malhal, I appreciate the edit, but I actually think that it's not the right way to highlight the approach. In this simple case, yes - you can alter the original publisher, but the general approach I tried to highlight here was that you can prepend to any publisher, even if you didn't directly create it, at the point of `combineLatest`.